# Filter out rows based on past n days

Tags: python-3.x

I have a df with a date column and I want to filter out the rows based on the last n (for this example I am using 5) days. I have tried using this -

df[df.date <= (pd.to_datetime('2020-09-11') - datetime.timedelta(days = 5))]

But this gives out all the rows till 2020-09-06 and I want all the rows from 2020-09-06 to 2020-09-11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect.

```py
df[(df.date >= (pd.to_datetime('2020-09-11') - datetime.timedelta(days = 5))) & (df.date <= pd.to_datetime('2020-09-11'))]
```

You need to get the dates between `09-06` to `09-11`, so you need to set two conditions checking upper and lower limit.